# select rows with the condition that one variable is larger than a number, returns many rows with NA

Tags: r

The dataset has columns 8 columns and 49,048 rows
raw data is uploaded to dropbox
https://www.dropbox.com/s/u9r01rw8cgoepax/sample.xlsx?dl=0

[image]

I use following code to extract rows with variable Fhas value more than 100 but got many rows with missing value in variable F

```
x = read_excel("file path")
x = x[x$F>100,]
```

[image]

```
> m = (x[x$F>100,])
> summary(m$F)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
100.1   137.0   244.6   375.0   443.5  2490.0   43570
```

Comment: This happens if there are missings in F.  You may try `m = x[which(x$F>100),]`.  However, it is hard to tell without data...

Comment: @OttToomet thank you very much! I have uploaded the data to dropbox (https://www.dropbox.com/s/u9r01rw8cgoepax/sample.xlsx?dl=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems indeed to be the case.  You may check that F-s are mostly missing:

```
x <- readxl::read_excel("~/d/sample.xlsx")
summary(x$F)
```

Gives you

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
   0.00    0.00    0.00    3.55    0.00 2490.00   43570
```

If you just select with `x$F > 100` you get NAs where `F` is missing.  If you select with `which(x$F > 100)` you get only numeric indexes for the case where this is true.  So

```
x[which(x$F > 100),]
```

gives you a dataframe subset where all `F > 100` (and none is missing).

Comment: I thought when ask for value greater than a number, it would return FALSE if the value is NA. However, it actually returns NA.

Comment: Yeah, you may try `NA > 0`, `NA < 100` etc.  They all give you `NA`.  There is a quirk though: `NA^0 == 1`